# Touchpad double tap and two finger scroll is only working when press Window Keys/SuperKey on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, touchpad, multi-touch, synaptics, elantech

How do I make my touchpad working without having to press Window(super)Key? I am using Ubuntu 16.04.3, I don't use mouse. It is working normal before (Without have to press Win Key) when I first installed Ubuntu. But then suddenly about 2 weeks, it was not working that way anymore(just simple tap, double tap or two finger scroll is not working), and I found out that I have to hold on on win key to make my touchpad works.
my touchpad is
↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]

after I run: xinput list-props 13:
[xinput list-proos 13](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Hx3H.png)

Comment: I've written an answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/995819/touchpad-gestures-and-holding-keys-does-not-work/995948#995948). Let me know if it helps or you have questions by adding a comment below using @WinEunuuchsToUnix in the comment

Comment: This is what I did. From the article I did do 2 things. first I am running  "sudo rmmod psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse"  and second I did run "sudo apt-get purge xserver-xorg-input-synaptics" . The result is that I can scroll down the page and my curser did not jump around. So I thought it works then I restart my machine. Apparently all it back to does not working.  But I found from article somewhere to install touchpad indicator, and  I did this way I guess I set my touchpad to enable .  I know it is temporary, and I believe it is better way to do this. Thank you

Comment: I've posted a permanent fix so that `psmouse` is removed and inserted with every boot. Try it when you have time and let me know if your system works fine now. Thanks.

Comment: so I try this time with temporary fix you post ""sudo rmmod psmouse sudo modprobe psmouse" , but it did not work so I am not sure to try permanent fix. BTW, I have installed new kernel 4.14.0-041400-generic on my machine , and I have x86 machine.

Comment: If the temporary fix doesn't work permanent fix won't either. Kernel `4.14.0-041400-generic` is old. You would be better trying the newest kernel `4.14.14-041414-generic` to test the fix.

Comment: Hi @WinEunuuchs2Unix, I am trying with newest kernel 4.14.14-041414-generic as your advice. After reboot now  my touchpad with scrolling and and tap and double is all seems working very well. Thank you :-)

Comment: Glad to hear it. If you find performance an issue `4.14.13-041413-generic` might be 2% to 5% faster in operation. If you haven't done so already, kindly up-vote the linked answer so other other people know it works.